# open the content in chrome browser phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I need help resolving the error I get when I run a phonegap android app. I'm iframing a page with an embedded UStream feed. Everything else loads perfectly expects the ustream section and I get the error:

> Sorry! The stream could not be played on this device.
>   Open the Content in Chrome Browser

Any assistance you can offer will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably what is going on is that the UStream feed uses some HTML5 or other fancy API that is not yet in the WebView that Cordova/PhoneGap uses. You see, Phonegap uses a native WebView component to render the HTML content of your app. The problem is that this WebView is an oooold version of WebKit and doesn't support HTML5 and some other things. This is why the same web page will sometimes act differently depending on if you open it with Chrome browser, the standard Android browser, or with a Cordova WebView. This problem exists for all platforms as far as I know.

The slightly good news is that they just announced that Android 4.4 will have an [updated WebView based on Chromium code](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/webview/overview), so hopefully your iframe will work in a 4.4 version of Cordova.